# Simplify a composition of functions

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

How do I make Mathematica simplify, for example, `(1-#&)@*(1-#&)` into `#&`? `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` don't work. If I apply the composition to a symbolic expression `x` I get `x` back, but that isn't a function.

Comment: `(1-#&)@*(1-#&)` is not grammatical in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Can you post a complete example of what you are exactly looking for?

Comment: Let f = (1-#)&, i.e. f(x)=1-x. Mathematica can easily simplify f(f(x))=1-(1-x)=x. How can I make it simplify $f\circ f$ into the function g = #&, i.e. g(x)=x? (I'm referring to simplifying $f\circ g$ in the arbitrary case where it can be simplified, not just this example.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Is too!  Try `f=(1-#&)@*(1-#&);f[x]` (returns `x` as expected)

Comment: @2012racmpion Weird that the code includes `@*`... an unusual way to compose this function, but yes... functional.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I've found it useful when I compose built-in functions, for example I just used this today:  `Image @* Rescale /@ data` (instead of the 'normal' way `Image[Rescale[#]]& /@ data`).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork `@*` and `/*` are new operators introduced in version 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since,

```
Attributes[Function]
```

> {HoldAll, Protected}

Use `Evaluate`

```
f = Function[{x}, Evaluate[(1 - # &)@*(1 - # &)@x]]
```

> Function[{x}, x]

```
f@x
```

> x

Answer (score 2):

Different version of Bob Hanlon's solution:

```
f = (1 - # &)@*(1 - # &)@(# &)
(*#1 &*)
f@x
(*x*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to look

```
f = (1 - #) & (*your function*)
g[f__] := (a f@ # + b f@f@#)&   (*your arbitrary complicated function of function*)
h[x_] := Simplify[g[f][x]]  (*your final function*)
```

(I just wanted to use `Simplify` somehow)